# FindFirstFile Multiple file types

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible to use Windows API function `FindFirstFile` to search for multiple file types, e.g `*.txt` and `*.doc` at the same time?

I tried to separate patterns with `'\0'` but it does not work - it searches only the first pattern (I guess, that's because it thinks that `'\0'` is the end of string).

Of course, I can call `FindFirstFile` with `*.*` pattern and then check my patterns or call it for every pattern, but I don't like this idea - I will use it only if there no other solutions.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot specify multiple wildcards. You will have to use `*` and filter yourself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not supported.  Run it twice with different wildcards.  Or use `*.*` and filter the result.  This is definitely the better choice, wildcards are ambiguous anyway due to support for legacy MS-DOS 8.3 filenames.  A wildcard like *.doc will find both .doc and .docx files for example.  A filename like `longfilename.docx` also creates an entry named `LONGFI~1.DOC`

Comment: why would *.doc match *.docx?

Answer (score 6):

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mention nothing about `FindFirstFile` allowing multiple search patterns, hence it doesn't exist.

In this case your best bet is to scan using an open selection (like `C:\\some directory\*` or `*`) and then filter based on `WIN32_FIND_DATA`'s `cFileName` member, using [`strrchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strrchr/) (or the appropriate [Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftw0heb9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) variant) to find the extension. It should run pretty fast for the small set of characters that make up a file extension.

If you know the that all the extensions are say 3 characters, you should be able to mask it off as `*.???` to speed things up.

Comment: The performance issue is not how long it takes to filter the filename, since that's got to be done somewhere. It's the fact that you are hitting an API function again and again. However, FindNextFile is pretty performant in my experience so I doubt that it's a problem.